# Subsonic 3.0.0.4 active record templates for mysql not returning last inserted id

Tags: mysql, activerecord, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record, lastinsertid

Steps to reproduce error:

CREATE TABLE person (
person_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, firstname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, lastname varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, age int(11) DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (person_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

INSERT INTO person(firstname,lastname,age)
VALUES ('myname',NULL,NULL) ;SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as newid

```
    Person personObject = new Person();
    personObject.Firstname= "myname";
    personObject.Add();
    Response.Write(personObject.PersonId);
```

output is"0'

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report?

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or its just me.

Comment: now I believe this is a bug in mysql provider of the subsonic core class.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not a bug but rather an error that is likely to happen if you change the naming convention of columns and tables -> ToPascalCase. By default a column/table name is copied the way it is defined on the MySQL database. Which makes this ugly

Original

```
person personObject = new person()
personObject .person_id = 1;
personObject .first_name = "hello";
personObject .Save();
```

What I like to happen

```
Person personObject = new Person()
personObject.PersonId = 1;
personObject.FirstName = "hello";
personObject.Save();
```

There will be two(~3, can't remember now) major issues to the SubSonic core after changing the default template to generate the following names using SubSonic's inflector class.

reflection for properties that are required for UPDATES/INSERTS must be changed 
example:

```
//from
item.GetType().GetProperty(tbl.PrimaryKey.Name);
//to
item.GetType().GetProperty(Inflector.ToPascalCase(tbl.PrimaryKey.Name));
```

column names should be returned to its original property when doing inserts
example:

```
//from
GetColumn(key)
//to
GetColumn(Inflector.AddUnderscores(key))
```